# Pyodbc Error "A TVP's rows must be Sequence objects.", 'HY000'

Tags: python, json, api, pyodbc, table-valued-parameters

I am calling an API and moving the data from json to sql. When I try to post to sql I get this error:
Pyodbc Error "A TVP's rows must be Sequence objects.", 'HY000'

Here is my SQL Statement in python:

```
conn =  pyodbc.connect('Driver={ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server};Server=' + server+ ';Database=' + 
database + ';Trusted_Connection=yes')
cursor = conn.cursor()

for row in range(4):
    cursor.execute('''
            
          INSERT INTO [dbo].[IndustryCode] (id,name,billingAddress,frontOfficeId,link,isArchived,representativeUsers,statusId,status,industry,
                createdDate,lastUpdatedDate,lastActivityDate,latestActivityName,openJobs,street1,street2,city,stateOrProvince,postalCode,country,
                    county,geoCode,schoolDistrictCode,source) 
            VALUES(?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?)
            ''',
            (
            field1,     #id
            field2,     #name
            field3,     #billingAddress
            field4,     #frontOfficeId
            field5,     #link
            field6,     #isArchived
            field7,     #representativeUsers
            field8,     #statusId
            field9,     #status
            field10,    #industry
            field11,    #createdDate
            field12,    #lastUpdatedDate
            field13,    #lastActivityDate
            field14,    #latestActivityName
            field15,    #openJobs
            field16,    #street1
            field17,    #street2
            field18,    #city
            field19,    #stateOrProvince
            field20,    #postalCode
            field21,    #country
            field22,    #county
            field23,    #geoCode
            field24,    #schoolDistrictCode
            'PL1'     #source
            )
        )

    cursor.commit()
```

I am converting my data from json to a dataframe and from there, I am inputting it into sql.

Here is a sample of my input from my dataframe:

```
            field1  = df_t['id'].values[0]
            field2  = df_t['name'].values[0]
            field3  = df_t['billingAddress'].values[0]
            field4  = df_t['frontOfficeId'].values[0]
            field5  = df_t['link'].values[0]
            field6  = df_t['isArchived'].values[0]
            field7  = df_t['representativeUsers'].values[0]
            field8  = df_t['statusId'].values[0]
            field9  = df_t['status'].values[0]
            field10 = df_t['industry'].values[0]
            field11 = df_t['createdDate'].values[0]
            field12 = df_t['lastUpdatedDate'].values[0]
            field13 = df_t['latestActivityDate'].values[0]
            field14 = df_t['latestActivityName'].values[0]
            field15 = df_t['openJobs'].values[0]
            field16 = df_t['street1'].values[0]
            field17 = df_t['street2'].values[0]
            field18 = df_t['city'].values[0]
            field19 = df_t['state_Province'].values[0]
            field20 = df_t['postalCode'].values[0]
            field21 = df_t['country'].values[0]
            field22 = df_t['county'].values[0]
            field23 = df_t['geoCode'].values[0]
            field24 = df_t['schoolDistrictCode'].values[0]
```

Field25 is a constant, this is why it is in my sql statement.

Sample of my json:

```
{'id': 4177713, 'name': '', 'mainAddress': {'street1': None, 'street2': None, 'city': None, 'state_Province': 'AR', 'postalCode': None, 'country': 'US', 'county': None, 'geoCode': None, 'schoolDistrictCode': None}, 'billingAddress': None, 'frontOfficeId': 11259, 'link': 'https://apisite.comPyodbc Error "A TVP's rows must be Sequence objects.", 'HY000'/app/#/company/4177713', 'isArchived': True, 'representativeUsers': [151209], 'statusId': 6492, 'status': 'Delete', 'industry': None, 'createdDate': '2008-04-15T15:28:00', 'lastUpdatedDate': None, 'latestActivityDate': None, 'latestActivityName': None, 'openJobs': 0}
```

Comment: It seems that at least `df_t['representativeUsers'].values[0]` is giving you a list instead of a scalar. You'd need to do: `df_t['representativeUsers'].values[0][0]`, or even handle it by manipulating `df_t` beforehand. It might be a good idea to first fully understand what you'd be losing if you did that, and there were multiple values in that list...

Comment: I can remove the brackets in representativeUser. I have also removed the 'T' in the createdDate to make sure that wasn't giving me any issues.

Comment: Alright, then let us know what happens when you run it and update the answer if you're getting any other error.

Comment: Oh, you might get a TypeError or similar if you have a DATETIME field into which you're attempting to insert a string representation of a timestamp. You'd need to convert that column using something like: `df_t['createdDate'] = pd.to_datetime(df_t['createdDate'])`.

Comment: This worked. Thank you.

Comment: You're welcome. Best wishes with the rest of the project.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because df_t['representativeUsers'].values[0] has a string with '[]', adding
df_t['representativeUsers'].values[0][0] resolves my issue.